# comparing two variables using IF/IF..ELSE statement for PHP and inserting into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i am doing a count validation on two variables , $row2 with a value of 7 and $row3 with a value of 11. What i want to achieve is that the higher value can only be insert into the DB. The problem now is that $row3 value is bigger than $row2. however it always insert $row2 value into the DB. Is there any wrong with my validation codes?

```
function tweetCount($hashtag) {

$url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q='.urlencode($hashtag).'&rpp=100&result_type=recent';

//echo "<p>Connecting to <strong>$url</strong> ...</p>";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$xml = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//If you want to see the response from Twitter, uncomment this next part out:
//echo "<p>Response:</p>";
//echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($xml)."</pre>";

$affected = 0;
$twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
    $text = trim($entry->title);
    $author = trim($entry->author->name);
    $time = strtotime($entry->published);
    $id = $entry->id;

    //echo count($entry->text);
   // echo "<em>Posted ".date('n/j/y g:i a',$time)."</em><p>Tweet from <b><u>".$author."</u></b>: <strong>".$text."</strong>  </p>";
    //echo "<br/>";
}
    //echo count($twelemtnt);
    //echo count($entry);
    echo $number_of_tweets = count($twelement->entry);
}
```

on my html table , i echo the data out like this:

```
 <?php echo tweetCount($row[2]); ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="row2" value="<?php echo tweetCount($row2[2]);?>"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="row2Ini" value="<?php echo $row2[1];?>"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="row2Sch" value="<?php echo $row2[2];?>"  />
```

using a POST form i post it to another page where i need to do a count validation to see if which variable $row2 or $row3 have a higher count value and then i will insert the higher value into the DB

admin.php page

```
$row2 = $_POST['row2'];
$row2Ini = $_POST['row2Ini'];
$row2Sch = $_POST['row2Sch'];


if ( $row2 > $row3 )
{
    echo "<br>row2 is more than row 3";
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
            if (!$con)
              { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
            mysql_select_db("schoutweet", $con);
            $sql2="INSERT INTO matchTable (schInitial, schName,position)VALUES
            ('$_POST[row2Ini]','$_POST[row2Sch]','top4')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}echo "ROW2 record added!<BR>";
            mysql_close($con);
}
else if ($row2 < $row3)
{
    echo "row3 count is more than row 2";
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
            if (!$con)
              { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
            mysql_select_db("schoutweet", $con);
    $sql="INSERT INTO matchTable (schInitial, schName,position)VALUES('$_POST[row3Ini]','$_POST[row3Sch]','top4')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}echo "ROW3 record added!<BR>";
            mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Which block do you think is executing?

Comment: As an aside, don't forget to account for the case where they're equal, unless you really don't want anything inserted in that case.

Comment: Are you sure that $row2 and $row3 are numeric? Because if they are strings '7' is greater then '11' and all is correct.

Comment: Please check the output of `var_dump($row2, $row3);`

Comment: please provide code you are using for `$row2` and `$row3`.. You have problem in this only...

Comment: edited my question , do take a look (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never write connection twice... You should take connect part out of if..else statement...

Check below if it works...

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
        if (!$con)
          { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
        mysql_select_db("schoutweet", $con);


if ( $row2 > $row3 )
{
echo "<br>row2 is more than row 3";
        $sql2="INSERT INTO matchTable (schInitial, schName,position)VALUES
        ('$_POST[row2Ini]','$_POST[row2Sch]','top4')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}echo "ROW2 record added!<BR>";

}
else 
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO matchTable (schInitial, schName,position)VALUES('$_POST[row3Ini]','$_POST[row3Sch]','top4')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}echo "ROW3 record added!<BR>";

 }
            mysql_close($con);
```